# Keep .NET 5 Web API running all the time in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I have .Net 5 Web API hosted on IIS 10.

I configured IIS Application pool and IIS Site as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#application-initialization-module-1).

1. Install server feature - Application Initialization Module
2. Set the Start Mode to AlwaysRunning
3. Set Preload Enabled to True
4. Set the Idle Time-out (minutes) to 0 (zero)

The problem is - When I reset IIS(iisreset), app is not initializing. I see only app is shutdown in logs.

> 2021-10-26 16:35:16.5366|INFO|Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime|Application is shutting down...
> 2021-10-26 16:35:16.5366|INFO|Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler|Scheduler QuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.

What am I missing?

Comment: What's the hosting module you set? If you set out of process, it may useless because application is running on kestrel. IIS just a proxy server to forward request.

Comment: @BruceZhang hostingModel="inprocess"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out that for "Preload" = true on the Web Site to work you should activate **anonymous authentication** on the web site.

If anyone knows how to fix this for Windows Authentication only, please add your answer.